# How can I show user the menu I created again after selecting an option - Java

Tags: java

I am beginner and I want to show the user the below

```
System.out.println("Welcome to the client screen");
System.out.println("There are 3 Lotteries (Lotto, Jackpot and National)");
System.out.println("Please select one (L, J, N) or E to exit: ");
```

Menu again if they choose the options L J or N, therefore the user would then have to choose another letter again or choose to exit. Also I'm not sure I implemented case 'E' correctly but I think that is how I can show the previous login screen to the user again, so if someone could confirm that for me that would be great!

```
System.out.println("--------Login Screen--------");

System.out.println("Enter C for client and E for employee: ");

String login= s.nextLine();

if("C".equals(login)) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the client screen");
    System.out.println("There are 3 Lotteries (Lotto, Jackpot and National)");
    System.out.println("Please select one (L, J, N) or E to exit: ");
    String select= s.nextLine();

    switch(select){    
        case "L": 
                 break;
        case "J": 
                 break;
        case "N": 
                 break;   
        case "E": System.out.println("--------Login Screen--------");
                  System.out.println("Enter C for client and E for employee: ");
                  login= s.nextLine();  
                 break;
        default: System.out.println("Invalid Selection");
                 break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `while` loop to process the user input and a function to show the menu. While the input is still valid for a menu selection, you can keep looping to allow the user to interact with your program. When they select the quit option, `break` the loop.

Comment: i can't really understand sorry but i am a begineer if you could show me how from my example that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow the client menu to return to the login menu upon completion, add two while loops, one for the login screen, and one for the client screen as follows:

```
boolean loginScreenDone=false;

while(!loginScreenDone) {
    System.out.println("--------Login Screen--------");

    System.out.println("Enter C for client and E for employee: ");

    String login = s.nextLine();


    if ("C".equals(login)) {
        boolean clientScreenDone=false;

        while(!clientScreenDone) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the client screen");
            System.out
                .println("There are 3 Lotteries (Lotto, Jackpot and National)");
            System.out.println("Please select one (L, J, N) or E to exit: ");
            String select = s.nextLine();

            switch (select) {
            case "L":
                //call a method to handle Lotto here
                break;
            case "J":
                //call a method to handle Jackpot here
                break;
            case "N":
                //call a method to handle National here
                break;
            case "E":
                clientScreenDone=true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Selection");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please extend your answer with information on **what** you've changed and **why** you've done so.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method to display those messages, call it whenever you want to display them 
About case E I think it's correct (if I understand what you wana do correctly) but since in case e you look for input of E and C you need to accept the input (s.readLine()) over.

Comment: Well in your class or in any class that's up to you to figure :-)

Comment: i know how to make a method but the problem is that i want to first  run a code in case for example L and then show the menu again, when i tried it what was happening to me is the method shows before everything else exectutes inside the case

Comment: I don't really get this, so you want things to happend after you done processing in the switch? Since after each option you break out, add the method call out under the switch body, also if you mean that you want the program to run over after it has been terminated then use a while loop with a condition like while(boolean) where boolean signifies weather it runs or not.

Comment: I will try to explain more, so what i want is to first show the menu the user will enter a letter let say the letter L, the case L will run after it runs since it's not the exit I want to show the menu again and the user will be able to select a letter again, let say this time the user chooses E so that means it will exit the exit didn't work because it just shows the Login menu again but if i choose C it wont run the code for the client so that is another problem i have because i can't get the program to go back to previous "screen" i never done it before i wish i could find an example.

Comment: Have a buolean set true, and a while loop around your code that has as condition this boolean, so if e is selected it will set the boolean to false and therefore it will stop execuring :-)